# Restrict record visibility based on a field (even for the record owner)

Tags: sharing, owd, visibility

I have a requirement to hide any records of an object, when the 'Status' field is set as 'Closed'. I want to hide these records from a user, even if he is the owner of the record. Is there any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered changing the owner when the record becomes Closed, assuming you are using sharing rules?

Comment: Yes, I have considered this solution, but for reporting reasons I would like to keep the 'real' owner of the record.

Comment: Record ownership is at the core of SF record access capabilities and I don't think you would be able to restrict a record owner from at the least being able to view the record. Create a custom field to capture owner info for reporting purposes and upon status change to `Closed`, consider copying the current owner into the custom field and change the actual owner of the record. Additionally, use sharing rules.

Comment: There could be few things you would need to consider with reference to reports and dashboards, but I'm sure there will be workarounds. Also, if you take this approach, don't end up taking a single user as new owner for all relevant records because this would lead to data skew in future.

Comment: Would it be possible to use criteria-based sharing rules instead of owner-based sharing rules here?

Comment: @PhilW Both criteria- and owner-based sharing rules could be used, but only after the record owner is changed. You might know that the SF record sharing and access model is all about opening up access from the most restrictive access to least restrictive access. And, the SF model doesn't exclusively facilitate restricting access. This requirement sounds like a request to restrict the access to the record owner without changing the owner, which is not possible IMO.

Comment: If the criteria were based on the status and owner I was thinking that might take the record out of the sharing group. Still, I'm not a sharing expert and only know there are significant limitations on what you can do with criteria-based sharing.

Comment: Most of my sharing experience is based on Ownership and Roles combined with Apex Sharing. The latter is, of course, an option. Drop OOTB owner-based sharing and replace with Apex creation and/or deletion of sharing records based on owner and status fields.

Comment: @PhilW Criteria based sharing would open up access to new users or groups, but will not restrict the implicit access the record owner has already. As mentioned in your previous comment, apex managed sharing would be another option, but that too requires changing the owner on the Share object record (_that has rowcause listed as `owner`_).

Comment: @arut my suggestion was to remove ownership-based sharing first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117169/discussion-between-arut-and-phil-w).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Summarizing the key points from the comments as an answer (so those looking for an answer don't have to go thru all the comments).*

Record ownership is at the core of SF record access capabilities and none of the record access or sharing mechanisms (such as OWD, Object permissions, Role hierarchy, Sharing rules etc.) in Salesforce can be used to modify the access the record owner implicitly has on his/ her records. So, there is no way to remove access on a record for its owner. SF sharing & access model works on the principle of opening up access from the most restrictive access to least restrictive access and there is no explicit way to restrict access for specific users (after opening up access for a group of users).

Workaround to this problem is to create a custom field and copy the original owner field into this custom field for reporting purposes, if needed. Change the owner via apex when the record hits a certain required condition or, *as pointed out by **@PhilW***, use apex managed sharing (after revoking the ownership). Other existing sharing rules and role hierarchy will have to be checked so the user doesn't get access to the record thru one of these after his/her record ownership is revoked.